# How do I place/anchor showerhead at a low height, without drilling the wall?

Tags: bathroom

**Situation**:

- I have a bathtub with a shower-head
- The shower-head is attached via a mount point which is very high (~ height of raised hand of an adult)

  - This means a child cannot reach the shower-head to take it off/put it back on if needed if it's in the "proper" place, hanging from the mount. **Too high to reach**!

**What can I do to remedy this situation?**

Just to be clear, I do NOT need the shower-head to be acting as a shower when placed - I just need it to be on, AND not spraying water all over the bathroom.

***Constraints:***

- **What I need**: a way to place the shower-head at a height that a small(ish) child can reach. Say, less than 4 feet from the bath floor, ideally less than 2 feet.
- The showerhead **must be on**, and when on, should NOT spray water anywhere except into the bathtub.
- **What I do NOT need**: Don't care if - when placed - water pour over the person. As long as it ends 100% in the bathtub.
- I do NOT want to drill holes in the wall to install a new mount point for the showerhead.
- The shower mount is such that you CAN hang things from it. E.g. right now a shower organizer hangs from it
- There is a faucet in the bathtub, but placing the running shower-head on it doesn't work (see next section)
- Showerhead is on a flexible hose, the length of the hose is such that, when fully extended, the head almost reaches the bath floor.
- Shower walls are **tiled**
- Buying a new shower head (or an extension replacement) isn't an option.

**What I tried:**

- Just take the showerhead off, and let it hang down.

  This failed because when turned on, the shower spray jet-pushes the head in all sorts of directions, and being on the end of flexible hose, it flies and thus sprays all over the place.
- Place the shower-head on the bathtub's faucet

  This works when the water is OFF. However, when you turn it on, the water jet's force is enough to EASILY dislodge the head from the faucet and it falls to previous free-hanging issue.
- Attach a small holder to the tiles on the wall with suckers.

  The suckers easily disconnected after 1 shower.

Comment: Even thought it's nice you took the time to be very descriptive about the issue, I feel like a couple of pictures could be of help.

Comment: Good job on the Explorer hat! Fancy helping out a fellow hatter [here](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10352/how-to-avoid-paper-sticking-together-in-a-printer) (not SFF)? ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor - TY. I got tired of asking about NOT "actual problems" on SFF  and decided to ask about actual ones :)

Comment: Find yourself a suction mounting type holder (strong one, I bought a few in ikea, for hanging towels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some insulated wire that hangs from the fixture down to a lower point to secure the head.  This could attach to a ring or horse shoe-shaped holder for the shower head.

I suggest insulated wire as a coat hanger or the like will no doubt tarnish quickly.  You could also use rope or string.  If it's not steady enough it could be stabilized with weights or using metal rods.

Current state:

```
\
 *
```

Proposed state:

```
 \
  \
   |       
   |
   |<--- wire, rope, or rod
   |
   |
   |-o*

Where:
o= ring or u-shaped holder for shower head
*= showerhead
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you don't want to fasten an extra mount in the tiles of the wall as it punctures the wall. Another option could be to utilize the edge of the bathtub and the existing mount. In between these you could wedge a plank or piece of metal onto which you could mount a new mount at any height required.

If done correctly, this extra piece can be locked around the upper mount so that it stays firmly in place, and still provide a good extra place for your extra shower mount.